# Android emulator not detecting host audio input

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

I am attempting to set up an Android emulator that is capable of receiving the host machine's audio input. This should be perfectly feasible, given the recent [release notes found here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator).

I've attempted the following:

- Enabling the "Virtual microphone uses host audio input" found in
  extended controls.
- Launching an emulator via command line with the `-allow-host-audio` option.
- Toggling host microphone support via `adb emu avd hostmicon`.

With each attempt I try to use the built in Google assistant to see if it can hear me through my host machine, however it has yet to work.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone got this working?
2. Is the feature currently broken?
3. Does anything special need to be done on the host machine to support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Questions:

1. Has anyone got this working?

Yes

[image: Proof]

2. Is the feature currently broken?

See 1.

3. Does anything special need to be done on the host machine to support this?

Yes and on the Android emulator. Ensure your host default microphone is picking up audio at the correct volume. Test it in an application like Audacity.

The second most important thing is that you have the 'Google' app fully updated. I've found that after setting up a new Android emulator the voice to text microphone input does not work correctly. Once I run the Android x86 set up, sign in to Google Play, and then up date all of the currently installed Apps, the microphone / speech recognition engine will start working.

Also double check to ensure that 'Virtual microphone uses host audio input' is toggled on after closing and re-opening the emulator in the Android Studio emulator settings 'the three dots'. This will automatically turned itself back off after you close out the emulator.